# Ember.js in Component send Action with data to another Component

Tags: ember.js

Component action triggers perfectly.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
      searchField: function() {
        console.log('searchField');
        this.sendAction('searchField');
      }
    }
});
```

Route does not get triggered.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
      searchField: function() {
        console.log('ROUTE');
      }
    }
});
```

Handlebars

```
{{input key-up='searchField' searchField=(action "searchField")}}
```

I have spent so much time with this I am starting to lose interest with Ember.js, as I have also tried according to the documentation, but I get the same result.
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_sendAction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendAction` will not reach to `route`.
You have two options,

1. define `searchField` function in controller and from there you can route function`this.send('searchField')`
2. To directly call from component to route, there is addon `ember-route-action-helper` for this.

`ember install ember-route-action-helper`

Refer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653831/5771666) for more info.
To play around - [Sample Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/bdce15cf467f0af4a35e888b6126f676?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component2.hbs)

Comment: I'd prefer `ember-route-action-helper`. If you don't use that, your components have to be aware that whether they are placed in another component's template or a route's template.

Comment: @ykaragol how would one make a component aware that it is being placed in a controller

Comment: @kumkanillam I voted this correct as it works and gives me my solution, however a note to take is that it only works if the component.js actions are empty.

Comment: @ChristopherBecker A component has to be use `send` function if it is placed in a route's template. If you use `ember-route-action-helper`, you can use closure actions.